# mac os zsh git-prompt.sh cannot get colors to work

Tags: git

I copied git-prompt.sh (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) to ~/.git-prompt.sh

Then in my .zsrhc I have

```
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
setopt PROMPT_SUBST ; PS1='[%n@%m %c$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

The branch shows but it doesn't show color.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but are you sure your terminal emulator supports color?

Comment: Yes, the git status and git branch commands work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloring is enabled in line 557:

```
# NO color option unless in PROMPT_COMMAND mode
if [ $pcmode = yes ] && [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS-}" ]; then
    __git_ps1_colorize_gitstring
fi
```

You can either get rid of the whole if condition and just leave
`__git_ps1_colorize_gitstring` or enable `precmd` which is ZSH
equivalent for PROMPT_COMMAND and what `pcmode` stands for here and
enable GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS:

```
$ source ~/.git-prompt.sh
$ GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=true
$ precmd () { __git_ps1 "%n" ":%~$ " "|%s" }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in Git upstream for which I've sent the fix several times.

I have the [fix](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/commit/f0b7f2b0becc34113af85eb054731e0f390af94b) in my fork: [git-completion](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/).

You still need to set `GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1` though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that once colors are working, you can get *another issue: "[I have a fancy prompt with colors, and now bash doesn't seem to know how wide my terminal is. Lines wrap around incorrectly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053)"

For that, use With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), which lifts the limitation that colored prompts can only be used with `PROMPT_COMMAND` mode.

See [commit 7ee1af8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ee1af8cb8b97385fc4e603bc024d877def5adb4) (28 Feb 2023) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6041a13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6041a13ec2958b5c39a5f2bbadfffb4d4ce79d46), 28 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ee1af8cb8b97385fc4e603bc024d877def5adb4): prompt: use generic colors
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>
> <sup>Tested-by: Joakim Petersen</sup>

> When the prompt command mode was introduced in [1bfc51a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bfc51ac814125de03ddf1900245e42d6ce0d250) (Allow __git_ps1 to be used in PROMPT_COMMAND, 2012-10-10, Git v1.8.1-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5471fb1c4ca09c8a9e1ecb8d8caee80959bc081c)) (Allow __git_ps1 to be used in `PROMPT_COMMAND,` 2012-10-10), the assumption was that it was necessary in order to properly add colors to PS1 in bash, but this wasn't true.
>
> It's true that the `\[ \]` markers add the information needed to properly calculate the width of the prompt, and they have to be added directly to PS1, a function returning them doesn't work.
>
> But that is because bash coverts the `\[ \]` markers in PS1 to `\001 \002`, which is what readline ultimately needs in order to calculate the width.
>
> We don't need bash to do this conversion, we can use \001 \002 ourselves, and then the prompt command mode is not necessary to display colors.
>
> This is what functions returning colors are supposed to do.